# A connection was leaked

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a HTTP handler class that will handle the calls to a ASYNC method. Everything works fine, I am able to gather information from the json and display it inside of the application, however, I have noticed that I sometimes get the following in my log.

```
A connection to http://www.abc123.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

Is there any specific reason why I would be getting this. I am closing in within the try method in convertStreamToString.

```
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wich line throughs exception?

Comment: doesnt tell me. and it doesnt read anything from the tags in the makeservicecall method

Comment: can you show use full log from this error

Comment: Give me a few, it doesnt happen when I make the call...happens sometimes... ill report back

Comment: Some how you are not closing the connection,  put log after last line of try (wich mean codes runs successfully)  and check when this error happend wich code in try not runs completely and you can find out what causes this error

Comment: hmmm... i added in.close() after the respone= in the first method and I havent seen a leak yet. Weird, because it closes from the top method to the bottom. whatever.

Comment: keep try with logs you will find it